# Nvidia X server disable

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04

I have Nvidia 820M graphic card  on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04

System Info:- Dell 3558 i3/8Gb/1Tb/2Gb gfx

In additional drivers it's not showing, so I downloaded the driver from Nvidia Website

When I'm installing it, it gives a message to disable X Server
So I tried to use --no-x-check

But I got the error The Nouveau Kernal driver is currently in use, this driver is incompatible with Nvidia driver, disable it before proceeding

And Will I face any problem if I install it

Comment: Can you manually install it using the command:
`sudo apt install nvidia-367`?

Answer (score 0):

Nouveau driver module has to be disabled first. Add

```
blacklist nouveau
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/backlist.conf`, run

```
update-initramfs -u
```

and then reboot the machine.

X server should also be stopped before you start the installation:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Comment: that just led to a cursor prompt and nothing else